# SharePoint My Site and My Profile Question

Tags: 2010

I recently upgraded my SharePoint 2007 to 2010. I have multiple site collections listed as below.

- /personal/user1
- /personal/user2
- /personal/user3

In the new SharePoint 2010, when a user clicks on My Site, I want it to redirect to their personal page.

When they click on My Profile, I would like it to point to mysite/Person.aspx?accountname=username

Maybe this isn't possible, but I will take suggestions. Thanks for the help!

**Update:** So I have now created a Site Collection called /personal. I have set a managed path for personal as an Explicit inclusion.

```
My Site Host = http://spsite/personal
Personal Site Location = personal
```

The user's My Profile and My Site page are working, but when I choose My Content from the My Site page, I keep getting the error, "There has been an error creating the personal site. Contact your site administrator for more information."

Answer (score 0):

Offhand the first issue that comes to mind is your Application Pool Identity. You need to make sure the Application Pool Identity is also a Farm Administrator. You can do this through the Central Administration. Also it would be helpful if you could please pull the logfile of the error.